# Very Complicated Taz about Bracha on a Safek

Tags: blessing, maaser-tithes

I may be reading the Taz wrong in סימן סז, in אורח חיים, but it seems very perplexing to me. 
He writes: "לפי שכל דבר שהוא ספק של תורה מברכין עליו כמו בהפרשת דמאי." 
I thought that everyone agrees there is no Bracha on separating Dmai, so why does he bring this as an example of something that is a Safek Deoraysa and has a Bracha?
Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right off the bat, the Ba'eir Heitev [there](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x438) raises your question and suggests that there might be a typo:

> ומ"ש הט"ז כמו בהפרשת דמאי ע"ש הוא נגד המשנה במסכת דמאי פרק א' משנה
> ל' ומפרישין אותו ערום וכו' ע"ש  ואולי שט"ס הוא בדברי הט"ז

Alternatively a possible answer is that the Taz didn't mean that in the specific case of Demai there is a beracha; rather, he meant that the sugyah of Demai indicates the rule that anything which is a Biblical doubt gets a beracha. The Talmud discusses the beracha, or lack thereof, on Demai in [Shabbat 23a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=23&format=pdf).

> מתיב רב עמרם הדמאי מערבין בו ומשתתפין בו ומברכין עליו ומזמנין עליו ומפרישין אותו ערום ובין השמשות ואי אמרת כל מדרבנן בעי ברכה הכא כי קאי ערום היכי מברך והא בעינן והיה מחניך קדוש וליכא אמר אביי ודאי דדבריהם בעי ברכה ספק דדבריהם לא בעי ברכה והא יו"ט שני דספק דבריהם הוא ובעי ברכה התם כי היכי דלא לזילזולי בה רבא אמר רוב עמי הארץ מעשרין הן
>
> R. Amram objected: Dem'ai can be employed for an 'erub and for a joint ownership;  a benediction is pronounced over it, and grace in common is recited after it, and it may be separated by a naked person, and at twilight. But if you say that every Rabbinical [precept] requires a benediction, here, when one stands naked, how can he pronounce a benediction: lo! we require, therefore shall thy camp be holy [that he see no unclean thing in thee], which is absent? — Said Abaye, A certain Rabbinical law requires a benediction, whereas a doubtful Rabbinical law does not. But what of the second day of Festivals, which is a Rabbinical [institution] based on doubt, and yet it requires a benediction? — There it [was instituted] in order that it should not be treated slightingly. Raba said: The majority of the 'amme ha-arez tithe  [their produce].
>
> ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/shabbath/shabbath_23.html))

Here Rava and Abbaye debate *why* there is no beracha on Demai, but everyone apparently agrees that there is no beracha. However, the implication of the reasons given is that these are specific factors by Demai which make it not require a beracha, but if not for these specific factors then it *would* require a beracha. Perforce, then, the general rule must be that a Biblical doubt requires a beracha.

Indeed, R. Chaim Nathanson appears to argue as such in a responsum ([Divrei Chen Siman 27](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=144&st=&pgnum=53)) dealing with this:

> והבאה"ט דאתא לידן נימא בי' מילתא מה שהשיג על הט"ז בסימן ס"ז שכתב על דברי המחבר שהעתיק דינו של הרמב"ם בהא דספק קרא ק"ש חוזר וקורא בברכותיה וכתב ע"ז הט"ז וז"ל לפי שכל דבר שהוא ספק של תורה מברכין עליו כמו בהפרשת דמאי וכתב עליו הבאה"ט דדבריו הוא נגד המשנה דמסכת דמאי פרק א' ומפרישין אותו ערום כו' ואולי ט"ס הוא עכ"ל ובאמת דברי הט"ז נכונים שכונתו לדברי הראב"ד וחכמי לוניל בפרק ג' מהלכות מילה שהוכיחו מהא דיהיב רבא טעמא לדמאי שאין מברכין עליו משום דרוב ע"ה מעשרין [שבת כ"ג] משמע דאילו הי' מחצה על מחצה והי' ספק השקול הי' לן לברוכי אדמאי ומכאן שכל ספק מ"ע מה"ת שמחוייבין לעשותה מספק מברכין עלי' ג"כ וכן הביאו ראי' זו תר"י בברכות כ"א [ועי' בהגהת מהר"ם שם ועי' רא"ש ריש פרק כיסוי הדם ומעדני יו"ט שם וצ"ע וע' שבת כ"ג ועי' בהגר"א או"ח סימן תרפ"ח סעיף ד'] וז"ש הט"ז שכל דבר שהוא ספק של תורה מברכין עליו כמו בהפרשת דמאי ר"ל דלולא שרובא מעשרין הי' מברכין עליו ומינה לכל כה"ג בספק מ"ע של תורה דברי חן הלכות ברכות פרק א
> אלא דעיקר דברי הט"ז תמוהין שכתב כן על דברי השו"ע והרי השו"ע לא פסק כן אלא כהרמב"ם והרא"ש ריש פרק כיסוי הדם דעל ספק מ"ע אין מברכין וכמו"ש ביו"ד סימן רס"ה סעיף ג' ובאו"ח סימן י"ז סעיף ב' וע' בה"ג שם ביו"ד וכבר תפס עליו הגר"א ז"ל באו"ח שם סימן ס"ז מברכו ודו"ש באהבת ח"ן

Comment: Thank you! This is an excellent answer. I didn't know that any Acharonim (might) pasken like the Raavad!